# punctuation marks in javascript

Tags: javascript

can you guys plese help me to correct the punctuation marks in the javascript below? Found error when i paste in visual studio. I'm not familiar with javascript! Thanks guy...

```
function showLocalImage(imgname) {
  imgname = imgname.replace(/\\/g,”/”);
  imgname = imgname.replace(/\’/g,”\\’”);
  content = “<img src=\”" + String(imgname) + “\” border=\”0\” height=\”150\” weight=\”150\”>”;
  eval(‘document.getElementById(“imagepreview”).innerHTML=\” + content +”‘”);
  document.getElementById.imagepreview.style.visibility =’visible’;
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have fancy curly quotation marks (e.g. `”` or `’`) instead of straight quotation marks (e.g. `"` or `'`)?

Comment: Are those ”curly quotes” actually in your code? Start by replacing those with "straight quotes".

Comment: These code was found from internet and i have tried to replace all the fancy curly quotation marks with the straight quotation marks but i'm not familiar with javascript, so it still throws error....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because some of your quote characters are actually from a different character encoding, Use the following code:

```
function showLocalImage(imgname) {
  imgname = imgname.replace(/\\/g,"/");
  imgname = imgname.replace(/\’/g,"\\'");
  content = "<img src=\"" + imgname + "\" border=\"0\" height=\"150\" weight=\"150\">";
  var image_preview = document.getElementById("imagepreview");
  image_preview.innerHTML = content;
  image_preview.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

A couple of things:

- You should reuse DOM result sets and elements as much as possible to avoid having to run a query against the DOM every time you need to reference an element or set of elements.
- You should really try to avoid using the `eval` function as much as possible.

  **`eval` == EVIL**

Comment: Does the `new String(imgname)` actually do anything? Why not just `imgname` - it will already be a string from before...

Comment: @Michael, I was simply making the OPs code into working code without changing too much. Now that I can go back and edit it, I just swapped it with the variable itself. Good point.

Comment: My comment was directed half at you, and half at the OP. Now I see that we're both in agreement.

Comment: The 'imagepreview' actually is a div. Is it possible that i load the image found into the .net image control?

Comment: @WeeShian - I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use wrong quote characters (`” or ‘`). Replace them with " or ' and you'll be good. Use an ascii text editor, not a word processor for typing.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid `eval`, and declare the `content` variable, as well as declare a reference to the `imagepreview` element:

```
function showLocalImage(imgname) {
  imgname = imgname.replace(/\\/g,"/");
  imgname = imgname.replace(/\'/g,"\\'"); //Is this really necessary?
  var content = "<img src=\"" + imgname + "\" border=\"0\" height=\"150\" weight=\"150\">";
  var img = document.getElementById("imagepreview");
  img.innerHTML = content;
  img.style.visibility ='visible';
}
```